# Full text search winrt (windows runtime, windows store app, etc)

Tags: windows-8, lucene, windows-runtime

I use Lucene.Net to search text files in a WPF app and was thinking of porting it over to a Windows Store app. When I tried to add a Lucene.Net using the package manager I get the error below. Is there any other library that offers fully indexed text search I can use for WinRT?

```
install-package : Could not install package 'SharpZipLib 0.86.0'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets     
'.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author
```

*SharpZipLib is a dependency of Lucene.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll caveat that I do not know if this will actually work, but it may hold promise.

SQLite has full text search (FTS), and SQLite is supported for Windows RT. [This article](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2) would seem to indicate full text search isn't turned on by default so a recompile would be needed. This also presumes that whatever other dependencies that (FTS + recompilation) brings in are also supported on Windows RT.

[Tim Heuer's blog](http://timheuer.com) is an excellent source on SQLite with Windows 8 apps, and he has this post on [how to compile SQLite](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/06/05/howto-video-using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) (before it was all packaged nicely as an extension), so it may be worth a shot to try it out.

Comment: I think I may end up liking this more than Lucene.Net for my purposes. Thanks for the suggestion!